# How to parse multiple xml files in android

Tags: android, xml-parsing

i have 8 xml files and i am able to parse a single file using sax but is there a way to parse all files. all 8 files have similar elements and i have to get the topic of each file in a list view, like list view containing 8 topics. how to do this, how to call each file dynamically from assets folder. Help me with some ideas, am stuck with this friends. Thanks in advance

Comment: What's the specific issue? Can't you just parse each one the same way you parse the first one?

Comment: how to get the 8 file names in a single list view Dave

Comment: Exactly as Ahmed said, add the name to a collection as you parse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a instance Collection which carry the aggregated parseing result
create method to process a single xml file that returns a collection
create a method that loops for files by calling the function and adding the result to the collection

```
/**
     * this will process file by file
     * 
     * @param xmlFilePath
     * @return
     */
    private Collection<String> parseSingleFile(String xmlFilePath) {
        // process xml file and extract the result into a collection
        return new ArrayList<String>();
    }

    /**
     * this will take all of your files
     * 
     * @param files
     * @return
     */
    public Collection<String> processBulkFiles(String[] files) {
        Collection<String> parsedresults = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (String xmlFilePath : files) {
            parsedresults.addAll(parseSingleFile(xmlFilePath));
        }
        return parsedresults;
    }
```

Comment: ahmed coudl you pls show me an example if u got any...thanks for helping me

Answer (score 1):

To get the xml from Assets folder use

```
AssetManager mgr = getAssets(); 
Inputstream ins = mgr.open("abc.xml");
```

decode it to xml content then parse it and store your value in arraylist.
Like this do for 8 files and store the value in same arraylist, Finally display the list in listview.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if i'm unterstanding right, but you could pass the Filename of the XML you click on in the List View to the next Activity and there use it to do your XML Operations.